# How to make Google Form send out a confirmation email to the user who filled it out?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

Is there any way to script a Google Form in a way that it automatically sends out an email with the form response summary to the user who filled it out?

The flow should be: 
- A user fills out a Google Form embedded on a website, the form includes "email" field
- Every time this happens, Google Form sends an email to the respondent with a summary of his answers in the form.

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Script to email form answers and questions to a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294405/google-script-to-email-form-answers-and-questions-to-a-user).

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific script to do what you're trying to do. It's called MCQ and it was created by Romain Villard.  It's a little tricky to use, but I've figured it out and I'm using it on a regular basis.