# Trying to launch a simple script to send a receipt after form is completed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Okay, so. I have written a simple script to send an email to anyone who completes my form on google docs. The problem is, i cannot get it to run, all i have is the guts to get the users email and send them an email. I have no means of launching the script. I have looked near and far trying to find a way to auto launch the script once the form is completed.

**Tl;dr** Trying to send a receipt confirming the form was completed.

here is the script:

```
function hallpassreceipt() {

  // Get the email address of the active user - that's you.
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Get the name of the document to use as an email subject line.
  var subject = 'Hall Pass';

  // Append a new string to the "url" variable to use as an email body.
  var body = 'This is a hall pass .';

  // Send yourself an email with a link to the document.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body); }
```

Comment: The code was ruined through the copy and paste. i can repost it and try to fix it if needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. No need to repost you just can edit this one. Select your script text and use **{}** option to format this as code.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).

You need to set up an Installable Form Response trigger. One example: [Google Script to email form answers and questions to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294405/google-script-to-email-form-answers-and-questions-to-a-user).